# Any gallery plugins that allow commenting on single images?

Tags: plugins, gallery

I am looking for a gallery plugin that will allow users to comment on each individual photo as opposed to the entire gallery. I have tried [Lazyest Gallery](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/lazyest-gallery/); however, it doesn't seem to be integrating well with another plugin I have installed called [Facebook Comments for WordPress](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook-comments-for-wordpress/) which I'm using to replace the default WordPress commenting system. Does such a plugin exist? Or perhaps there is a better solution? What do you guys think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually your Wordpress theme will have an "attachments.php" page that would have a "single view" of the image in question. For an example: http://twentyelevenphoto.wordpress.com/2011/05/25/an-image/mcm_5276/

That gives you a "single" view of your image as well as comments. To test to see if your site has this, create a gallery and make sure to check "Attachment Page" when setting the Link Thumbnail to option.

[image: Gallery Image Options]

Then view the post, click on the gallery image and it should take you to that images single page.

Comment: Thank you. Just curious but with this method, is there a way to easily upload photos to a certain gallery at a later time? I will have a gallery called 'fan photos' which will be constantly updated. I'd like the client to have an easy time doing this.

Comment: I would just assign it to a specific post or page (the "Fan Photos" post/page) and have them update it as they normally would.

Answer (score 0):

You need to also attach images to the post, then remove gallery attach new pics to the post and next add the gallery again. But this operation will probably remove the comments.